# How do I detemine if my Windows profile is messed up?

Tags: windows-10, user-profiles

About 6 weeks ago I replaced the hard drive in my Dell XPS desktop, with an SSD. Things have been great since then. Until last weekend when some odd behavior started to happen. Whenever I log into my Microsoft account on Windows I get this error:

[image]

If I try to open Word I get this error:

[image]

So it's affecting all of my Office apps (I've got a Microsoft 365 Family license), it is also affecting other non-Office apps. For example, I've got Windows Terminal on my PC. But I can no longer use it as I get this error message whenever I try to launch it:

[image]

However, these symptoms are only affecting my Windows account/profile. Both my wife and my daughter have accounts/profiles on this desktop. And both can run all the Office apps, Windows Terminal, etc., fine. So, I don't think whatever is wrong, is a system-wide problem. It looks to me like it's just my account/profile.

I'd like to know if I'm correct about that. How do I verify that there's a problem with my profile?

Comment: I think you have already verified because the other user accounts are working fine. Fixing the profile means replacing it. You need to copy everything out of the existing profile, make a new one and copy the information back into the new profile.

Comment: Oh, WOW! I didn't realize that's what it would take. How do I go about doing that? All I know is creating an account by signing into my Microsoft account. Do I have to create a new Microsoft account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have verified the profile is not working. Damaged profiles cannot be repaired but must be replaced.

Since your User Account is a Microsoft Account, you will want to replace it with the same account.

This is fairly tricky.

First, make a new Local Account which is a member of the Administrators group.

Now, logging in a yourself, copy all the documents, email, favorites. pictures and so on to an external drive. Do this very carefully.

Log in as the new Admin Local User.

Using Windows Explorer, copy the Microsoft Account user to the same external drive.

Now, click on My Computer (This PC) and select Properties. Click on Advanced System Settings on the left. Click on User Profiles button. Delete your Microsoft Account. Make sure you understood and did all the steps above.

Restart the computer, log in as the Local Admin, make your Microsoft Account, make it a member of the Administrator's group.

Log into the Microsoft Account, restore the files from the external drive, set up apps and you should be good to go.

Please review all this twice before starting, and then try replacing your account.

This is not trivial but it is what you need to do.

Good luck.

Comment: John, I have a second hard drive in the PC. I presume I could do these operations using that, correct?

Comment: Yes , you can use the second hard drive for the temporary profile data storage.

Comment: John, in the Advanced System Settings, under the User Profiles button, I saw a button labeled, "Copy To...". Is that another way of moving a profile?

Comment: For other than the default profile, "Copy To" is greyed out, so you must copy the contents of the other user folder using Windows Explorer from a user different than the user profile you are trying to copy.

Comment: john do I copy everything from the corrupted profile into the new local profile? If so, why not create the new local user/profile, make it an administrator, and copy everything from the old profile into it?

Comment: Copy data and documents from the old profile, favourites as well. These things will not damage your new profile at all.

Comment: John, I've done as you instructed. I've rebooted the machine. Logged into the local Admin account I created. Went into This PC | Advanced System Settings | User Profiles |  Settings button. The old profile is gone. However, when I brought up File Explorer, went to C:\Users I found the old profile folder there, with all files still in it. In the User Profiles dialog there's a profile named Account Unknown with a size of "?". What's going on?

Comment: You were going to copy the file from the old profile to an external drive. So the files would be where you put them. I think that would be the case. Please check the external drive.

Comment: The files from the old profile appear to be in the secondary drive.

Comment: That should be OK. Move those files to your new profile in their proper folders (Documents, Pictures and so on)